# Update ASP Datagrid row textbox based on value entered in another gridview textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the below ASP Gridview with two textbox Template field
I want to use onkeyup event of textbox A to change the value in  textbox B based on value entered in textbox A

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgw" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-condensed" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
        <HeaderTemplate >
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:CheckBox ID="LinkButtonEdit" runat="server" CommandName="viewinvoice" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block"
                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'></asp:CheckBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="D_NAME" HeaderText="District" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="R_MANAGER" HeaderText="Regional Manager" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DISTRICTMANAGER" HeaderText="District Manager" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PHONENUMBER" HeaderText="District Manager #." />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTAL" HeaderText="Total"  DataFormatString="{0:n2}"/>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty of Bags" SortExpression="">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtqty" runat="server" data-style="btn-inverse" Text='<%# Bind("QTY") %>' CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)" >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtamt" runat="server" data-style="btn-inverse" Text='<%# Bind("AMOUNT") %>' CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)" >
            </asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="D_ID" HeaderText="" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RMID" HeaderText="" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="D_MANAGERID" HeaderText="" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LASTDATE" HeaderText="Last disbursed" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PPK" HeaderText="" />
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Wrap="True" />
```

Comment: where is  your code associated with the key_up event.. also are you familiar with using Query String in asp web page..? please show all relevant code

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to modify the field of one template column textbox (b) with a another (in the same row) once the use has exited. You will probably want to do this in the front-end using javascript and jquery (proior to postback.).

Comment: Yes exactly what I want to do, but I dont know how to go about it